# MySQL Update and dynamic multiple selection

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, foreach

I have form with a multiple selection, which has MySQL table column names as dynamic options.

```
<select id="rankRights" size="10" class="form-control" name="rights[]" multiple>
    <?php
        $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ranks");
        $rights = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($rights as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'Name' || $key != 'Id') {
                echo "<option value=\"".$key."\""; 
                    if($result[$key] == '1') { 
                        echo " selected"; 
                    } 
                echo "> " . $key . "</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

And in table there is user rights as columns and value 1 or 0 (means true or false, example below). There can be any number of columns.

```
.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
| Id   | Name       | ADMIN    | ADMIN_EDITUSER   | ADMIN_DELETEUSER   | etc     |
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
| 1    | Admin      | 1        | 1                | 1                  | ...     |
| 2    | Default    | 0        | 0                | 0                  | ...     |
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

What I want to do is update the values to 1 if user has selected column name in multiple selection and vice versa. How can I post those to the PDO query..

**EDIT:** So, if I submit the form (for example selected `ADMIN` and `ADMIN_EDITUSER` from multiple selection), I'll get POST params like `rights[]=ADMIN` and `rights[]=ADMIN_EDITUSER` -> in that case I want to update values of columns `ADMIN` and `ADMIN_EDITUSER` to 1, **and values of all other columns (options not selected) to 0**.

I have read following questions and thinking something, but I don't even now know how to do this.

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Depends how you would like to update your DB, do you want to submit your form or do you want to update it, without refreshing your page?

Comment: Do you mean AJAX combination with javascript listener?

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @PHPhil, I want to sumbit the form normally with page refresh. Javascript has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, problem is that I can't preset all the columns for query because they change. So in multiple select I have each column name as option value. How I can execute a query with updating columns are values from dynamic multiple selection? I don't know how to explain it better...

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I added a little more information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array of permission/column names:

```
$names = array('ADMIN','ADMIN_EDITUSER',...);
```

Initialize permissions to zero:

```
$permval = array();
foreach ($names as $name)
   $permval[$name] = 0;
```

Walk the posted values to set related permissions:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
  if ( isset($permval[$key]) )
    $permval[$key] = $value;
}
```

This at least gives you a defined list of values that you use can use to bind to a set of parameters - one for each permission name. Ensure the list of permission names and a statement preparation are kept in sync.

Any easier alternative may be to create a SQL statement on the fly but you may prefer to use PDO.

NOTE: I did not attempt to execute any of the above; it may contain typos!

Comment: How I can create an array of column names because number of them are not constant? Somehow with `foreach`?

Comment: @lingo, The number supplied are not constant but the number available to be supplied should be constant. Set them all to zero... and then override with the ones that get sent back, via post request, as set.